# C - char pointer and char pointer string management

Tags: c, string, pointers, arrays

I have to input a string and display it to standard out put.

The ideal solution would be to acquire the string into a char pointer array, however I get an error on the scanf, I presume because the char pointer string solution there is no space allocated for it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>


int main(void) {

char *charString;



printf("Input string - max %i caratteri: ",CHARARRAYSIZE);
scanf("%s", charString);

printf("%s",charString);


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Therefore I resorted to acquiring the sting into into a char array and then copy (strcpy) into a char pointer string.v In this case I get a warning saying that on the strcpy call sayng that strcpy is used without being initalized. How do I fix this?

Please find below the code for this second case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>



#define CHARARRAYSIZE 16


int main(void) {

char *charString;
char charArray[CHARARRAYSIZE];


printf("Input string - max %i characters: ",CHARARRAYSIZE);
scanf("%s", charArray);

strcpy(charString,charArray);

printf("%s",charString);


return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve my aim and avoid using a char array

Comment: `charString` still doesn't have any memory allocated to it, so how do you expect the copy operation to succeed? You need to use `malloc` to allocate some heap space for the pointer to point to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate space for the characters:

```
charString = malloc(CHARARRAYSIZE+1);
```

Later, you need to free them

```
free(charString);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't initialize the pointer to point to anything.  You can allocate memory on the heap for it using `malloc()` but make sure you `free()` it when you are done with it or you will leak memory.  For example, alter your original code block to look like this:

```
/* You need + 1 to store the terminating null character. */
char * charString = malloc(CHARARRAYSIZE + 1);

/* ... */

free(charString);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Comment: Ok thanks. for your answer. That was the problem. However, since @Johnny Mopp has a lower reputation than you, I am going accept his answer as that would help him more than it would you. Are you ok with that?

Comment: @geraldCelente Ultimately it's your call. SO guidelines are to accept the answer that was the most helpful as this will assist future visitors with the same question.

Answer (score 1):

The use of a char array is not helping you here at all.... `strcpy(charString,charArray);` is still writing to an address that is undefined!

You *must* have space allocated to scan your data into. That space can be local (such as your local character array) or it can be elsewhere (such as through a `malloc()` allocation), but it cannot be random as you're currently doing or bad things will happen.